# Help identify mystery part?

Tags: tire, pump

[image]This piece came with a CCM tire pump and I have no idea what it is or what it’s for. Can anyone tell me? Thanks.

Comment: Photos of the tire pump itself would be helpful. Could this just be part of the retail packaging? -- the top triangular hole looks like a hole to hang the item on a display rack.

Comment: And it was probably tied to that packaging by zip ties through those holes.

Comment: Yep, looks like a hanger to hang the pump on the sales display.

Comment: On the one hand, i hope this is a joke, and on the other hand i hope it's a neoenvironmentalist comment on the amount of material wastage in retail packaging.

Comment: It’s not just packaging. It’s so you can hang the pump up for storage. Fairly common on low end pumps.

Comment: @Andrew how would that work?  You're supposed to zip-tie your pump back into the packaging?  Or leave it on the pump permanently ?

Comment: @criggie the shown piece attaches permanently to the top of the pump barrel so it can be used to hang the pump on a hook. If you look at sales ads for pumps you should be able to find demonstrations of its use.

Comment: @criggie for example: https://www.walmart.com/ip/Zefal-Air-Storm-100-PSI-Bike-Pump-Sports-Ball-Toy-Compatible/460355732?wmlspartner=wlpa&selectedSellerId=0&wl13=2250&adid=22222222421&wmlspartner=wmtlabs&wl0=&wl1=g&wl2=m&wl3=501107745824&wl4=pla-293946777986&wl5=9015699&wl6=&wl7=&wl8=&wl9=pla&wl10=8175035&wl11=local&wl12=460355732&wl13=2250&veh=sem_LIA&gclid=Cj0KCQjwmcWDBhCOARIsALgJ2QcrDDr8ec8yRX-I1o-oXiFrpzXVszsDZtvNg5VHpuNzxHAbExTOYj0aAthjEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds

Comment: Sounds like an answer to me @Andrew.